# How can i set that the ffmpeg.exe will work as process from the directory i run my application exe file?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this two files :

ffmpeg.exe
myprogram.exe

myprogram.exe need the ffmpeg.exe 
Now in my code i have this :

```
workingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath)
```

So ffmpeg.exe is in the workingDirectory path folder.
But i want to make that if my brother will put ffmpeg.exe and myprogram.exe in lets say a directory called d:\test123 he will be able to run the program from there without the need to copy ffmpeg.exe to the workingDirectory .

So workingDirectory will be any directory the user put this two files .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `ffmpeg.exe` stand-alone without needing a bunch of additional support files?  If so, one option would be to simply copy this executable into your project and deploy it on compilation.  Then, a copy always exists in your deployment.

Comment: stand-alone how do i deploy it ?

Comment: When you copy the exe into your project, you go to the properties of that object and select an option under `Copy to Output Directory` which is appropriate.